# Is it possible to use the same TreeBuilder root for multiple bundles

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I would like to know how to have 2 bundles using the same TreeBuilder alias.

In my case, I have the next configuration:

```
harmony:
  site_name: 'Site name'
  theme: 'default'
```

And I would like to have the `site_name` defined by a bundle and the `theme` parameter by an other bundle.

Actually, to achieve that I create 2 Configuration classes.

The first containing:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode    = $treeBuilder->root('harmony');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('site_name')
                ->isRequired()
                ->info('The name displayed as the title of the site (e.g. company name, project name).')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

The second:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode    = $treeBuilder->root('harmony');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('theme')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->defaultValue('default')
                ->info('The theme used to render the frontend pages.')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

However I get the next exception message:

> **Unrecognized option "theme" under "harmony"**

I assume that my first bundle is checking for extra keys and found the `theme` key who is defined in the second bundle.

Is there to way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an alias bundle by overriding a parent method in a second bundle extension class : return 'harmony'.

see documentation, it's explain how DI check a bundle configuration:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class